# Keras model for image classification makes same prediction

Tags: machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, vgg-net

Novice here! I've been working on an image classification model in Keras for the past week or two. I've followed some tutorials online to perform transfer learning using VGG16 and Sequential. I've been using the food-101 dataset and I know that I have an overfit model (99% acc and 70% val_acc). I'm running into an issue where no matter what image I give to my model it will always give the same prediction. I'm using Dropout and L2 to regularize data, but I'm stumped as to what is causing the model to continually give the wrong prediction.

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=512, activation='relu', input_dim=7*7*512))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units=512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.00001)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units=512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.00001)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units=512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.00001)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units=15, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-4),
          loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['acc'])
```

Comment: You also fit your model at some point, don't you?

Comment: Do you use a balanced part of the food-101 dataset ? I see 15 units for the ouptut layer for a 101 classes dataset so I assume you are not using the whole dataset. So maybe it comes from the way you splitted your data.